# Can I transfer enchantments from one item to another?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I currently have a thaumium pickaxe with Efficiency IV, Unbreaking III, and Repair II. What I would like to transfer these enchantments to a thaumium sword (not crafted yet) and hopefully get the thaumium from the pickaxe back as well. Is this possible? If so, how? I am using the Feed The Beast Ultimate pack, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.5.1, MineFactory Reloaded has an Auto Dis-Enchanter, which unenchants anything put in it. according to [the post on the Minecraft Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1629898-151152-powercrystals-mods-the-updates-never-stop/):

> This machine has two input and two output slots. Enchanted items and books are placed in the inputs. When it completes, it will remove one enchantment at random from the item and install it on the book. The item will then be damaged - if this would destroy the tool, it will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

This may be possible using the [Uncrafting Table](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Uncrafting_Table) added by the [Twilight Forest mod](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Twilight_Forest), although I'm not sure if it works with regards to converting from one type of tool/weapon to a different type (i.e. pick to sword). The relevant excerpt from the wiki:

> The Uncrafting Table also allows you to recraft items, which is often used to keep a rare enchantment on an item. The Uncrafting Table can also swap enchantments from one item to another. For example,an Ironwood Sword with Knockback 2 and Smite V can be recrafted into a diamond sword with more durability for the cost of 27 levels of experience. The experience levels are generated with the amount which the enchantment is roughly created at, meaning the rarest enchantments will cost the most experience levels.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think its possible to transfer an enchantment from one item to another but its very possible to combine enchantments Via an anvil,Combining duplicate items with different existing enchantments into a single item that has the enchantments of both.This costs experience points.in this process, you will be sacrificing one item in exchange for the other, and i think they have to be items of the same kind for example iron sword and iron pickaxe so this should certainly work for you.

Comment: You are unable to merge Swords with Pickaxes.

Comment: you don't actually combine them, you destroy one, take the enchantment and move it to another item with the same material

Comment: Please explain this process in your answer.